# Powershell script to read 2 columns data from .csv file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to get of 2 column of a csv file:

```
ProductName          ProductCode
-----------------------------------------------------------
Java 7 Update 67     {26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789012}
Java 8  Update 25    {26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-902341562789}
```

I want to get only `ProductCode` column values to use in a foreach loop.

I tried in below way

```
$code1 = Get-Contect %path% | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -split '\s+' | Select-object -skip 1 | Select-Object -Last 1
} 

foreach($code in $code1){ write-host $code }
```

I'm getting below output

```
67,{232424-55567-8879-xxxxxxx} 
25,{324356456-5674-xxxx-xxxxxx}
```

But I want output only product codes like

```
{3245345345-3454-56656757-xxxxx}
```

Comment: I tried in below way $code1 = Get-Contect %path% | Foreach-Object { $_ -split '\s+' | Select-object -skip 1 | Select-Object -Last 1 } foreach($code in $code1){ write-host $code } I'm getting below output 67,{232424-55567-8879-xxxxxxx} 25,{324356456-5674-xxxx-xxxxxx} But I want output only product codes like {3245345345-3454-56656757-xxxxx}

Comment: Please add it to your question for better readability

Comment: The code above works for me correctly (except that you need to use `| Select-object -skip 1` before `foreach`). Are you sure that the format you provided in your question is exactly what you have in your file? Please try to open it in `Notepad++` and use `View > Show symbol > Show all characters` (or use any other program to check which characters you have in your file).

Answer (score 2):

This doesnt really look like CSV. I'd say the easiest way of doing this is something like this:

```
Get-Content %path% | Foreach-Object { $_ -split '\s+' | Select-Object -Last 1 }
```

This way you will get the last object after splitting string on multiple spaces

ps. if you need to skip the header you can add `| Select-Object -Skip 1` after get-content
pps. if import-csv allows for regex in `delimiter` import csv would be easier to use, but I doubt it allows for that.
ppps. works for me:

```
> cat .\Untitled-2.txt
ProductName ProductCode
Java 7 Update 67     {26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789012}
Java 8  Update 25    {26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-902341562789}
> Get-Content .\Untitled-2.txt | select-object -skip 1 | Foreach-Object { $_ -split '\s+' | Select-Object -Last 1 }
{26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789012}
{26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-902341562789}
```

Comment: I tried in below way



$code1 = Get-Contect %path% | Foreach-Object { $_ -split '\s+' | Select-object -skip 1 | Select-Object -Last 1 }
foreach($code in $code1){
write-host $code
}

I'm getting below output

67,{232424-55567-8879-xxxxxxx}
25,{324356456-5674-xxxx-xxxxxx}

But I want only product codes like {3245345345-3454-56656757-xxxxx}

Comment: hey, sorry, i dont understand. looking at your input nowhere I can find `67,` or `25,` so you either provided wrong input example or I dont understand something

Comment: Sorry for wrong input. In my .csv file in ProductName column I mentioned names as Java 7 Update 67 and Java 8 Update 25. You can see the same in Question I just edited.

Comment: weird, i copy\pasted your line into my powershell and get the proper result

Comment: I have created new .csv file and it working but output is coming with header name as well.

If I remove headers ProductName and Product i'm getting Correct output. Though those headers are not required.
If you have a way to not getting Header name i'm very helpful.

Comment: did you include `select-object -skip 1` into your command? that should skip the header, if you dont have a blank line before it

Comment: I included select-Object -Skip 1, and I don't have any empty lines before 1st line.

Comment: Hey Can we apply same code to .xlsx file instead of .csv ?

Comment: pretty sure xlsx is using some form of encoding - so no, but you can use com objects to work with excel and\or powershell excel module

Comment: The reason for asking about .xlsx, the above mentioned format is not staying after saving .csv File. Both columns combining in one line when I save the .csv file

Comment: sorry, i think this is a completely different issue and I can barely understand what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at how you are getting that information, as it will likely be easier to filter the information you want at source...

Using java as the example but the process could work with anything:

```
$java = Get-WMIObject Win32_Product | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "java*" }
```

`$java` will then contain the information about matching installations, you can then simply select the property you want and save that to file:

```
$java | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber | Out-File C:\folder\java.txt
```

Which will give you a file like:

```
{26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789012}
{26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-902341562789}
```